# regex - find and replace notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using notepad++.

I would like to find the following

`$result["value"]`

and replace it with

`$result->Items[0]->value`

So can anyone help me with regex?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but replace `\$result\["([^"]+)"\]` with `\$result->Items[0]->$1` These questions belong on superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Asad: That's what "vote to close" is for.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Forgot to vote, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me :

Find what: `\$result\["([^"]+)"\]`

Replace with: `$result->Items[0]->\1`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
\$result\["value"\]
```

and replace it with

```
$result->Items[0]->value
```